# POJO How to set value for the List

Tags: java, lombok, pojo

I want to set something like this in my Object

```
"citizenships": ["IN"]
```

It is possible that I would need set more than one citizenships e.g. ["IN","FR"]
I have class

````
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Citizenships {

    private List<Citizenship> citizenships = null;

    private class Citizenship {
    }
}  ```

My object is like that
````

````
public class StudentPersonalData {

private String name;
private String surname;
private String birthYear;
private String gender;
private List<String> citizenships;} ```
````

I have StudentPersonalData st1 = new StudentPersonalData();
I want to use something like st1.setCitizenships(.....);

How can I fill setCitizenships (....)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to call `setCitizenships` with any number of arguments.

i.e. you want to be able to call `st1.setCitizenships("IN")` and `st1.setCitizenships("IN", "FR");`

### Solution:

Use varargs in your function's parameters.

```java
// StudentPersonalData.java

public void setCitizenships(String... citizenshipsArr) {
    // Add every element in citizenshipsArr into your list
    for (String citizenship : citizenshipsArr) {
        citizenships.add(citizenship);
    }
}
```

This lets you call `setCitizenships` with 0 or more arguments of type `String`.

Note: Inside your function, `citizenshipsArr` can be used as if it was a `String[]`.

To better understand varargs, I'd recommend you to read this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your structure, as you have a class of citizenships on top, but you use a List of strings later.

Maybe the following code will help you

```java
st1.setCitizenships(List.of("IN","FR"));
```